# Docusign API - How to decrease the time taken by the API's to generate the signing URL?

Tags: docusignapi

I have integrated Docusign in my web application for e-signing ceremony. Now the problem is for generating the signing url it is taking around 12-15 sec out of which

Create Envelope API is taking around 6-8 sec 
Generate Signing Url API is taking 4-6 sec

So till the time url generates user has to wait which is too much for a user. User may leave the website. Is there any way to decrease the time taken by these API's or any workaround?

Comment: The issue is probably not to do with your code if you are able to complete a ceremony. Could be a network issue, can you run a speed test?

Comment: Internet speed is fine. Not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed would be faster in the production environment, but it would still take 8 seconds or so (6-10 seconds range, depending).
The first call depends in part on the size of the document(s) you send for signature. These have to first be converted to PDF that takes time. Using PDF directly is faster, or using HTML if you're using responsive signing.

Also, binary transfer of the file vs. using a string with base64 encoding could make a small difference if the file is large.

Comment: In my case size of the document is in KB and also i am using TemplateId for Envelope creation. So no uploading involved.

Comment: do you have UI that is tied to the API call? that is, the few extra seconds is causing a bad user experience?

Comment: You could have draft envelopes prepared ahead of time ready to go and if you need recipients update - do it later, that should be faster too.

Comment: Thank you. I got the above point. But what if there is a dependency on the document being generated in the web application and needs to be uploaded to Docusign. Can we decrease the time in this case?

Comment: yes, you could use binary upload instead of base64 - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/send-binary